# How to say 'deep fried' in French?

Tags: traduction, québec, alimentation, france

Native speaker here, and have recently realised that I can't seem to find a term to describe the process of [deep frying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_frying) - on which there is, interestingly enough, no article in French (despite there being one in 30-odd other languages). A quick check on Linguee and Reverso Context seems to only offer the generic 'frit', which is of course not specific to *deep* frying. A Google search does seem to reveal one option - 'cuire à grande friture' - but this seems to be primarily used on Québécois pages, and is something I've never actually heard in France. Am I the only Frenchman who hasn't heard this expression, or is it more common than I think? Is there another expression I'm missing, somewhere?

Comment: "How to say 'deep fried' in French?": You don't.

Answer (score 6):

En France on parle communément de [friture](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friture)  que ce soit pour la cuisson dans une poêle (*shallow frying*, ou tout simplement *frying*) ou dans une friteuse (*deep-frying*). Parfois on parle de « cuisson en pleine friture » pour l'équivalent du *deep-frying*, mais pas fréquemment.

La « friture » (nom) est le résultat d'un aliment qu'on « fait frire » (verbe).
Il suffit pour s'en convaincre de regarder sur divers sites culinaires les recettes de cuisson des frites, aliment qui correspond par excellence à la cuisson en pleine friture pour s'en convaincre. Et on trouve en illustration la cuisson des frites sur wikipedia aussi bien à [*deep-frying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_frying) qu'à [friture](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friture), et la liste des aliments pour les deux articles est en partie commune (avec des variations culturelles imposées par les habitudes culinaires).
L'instrument dans lequel on fait frire s'appelle une [friteuse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friteuse),  ce qui en anglais s'appelle [*deep-fryer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_fryer).
L'huile dans laquelle on plonge l'aliment s’appelle le [bain de friture](https://www.supertoinette.com/glossaire-cuisine/204/culinaire/friture.html/wiki/Friture).

Je ne connaissais pas le terme « cuire à grande friture » qui n'est pas employé en France  et une recherche m'a montré que ce terme est effectivement typiquement québécois, site de [recettes québécois](http://qc.allrecipes.ca/trucs-cuisine/2/cuire---grande-friture.aspx), un [livre de recettes québécois](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ixokHRLHKGQC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=%22cuire%20%C3%A0%20grande%20friture%22&source=bl&ots=VnxJAsNPHu&sig=eMpw-wCtSJh2Yhebm2LHi8geOwc&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiqs2o6K3SAhXI1hQKHdYUCkoQ6AEIQjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22cuire%20%C3%A0%20grande%20friture%22&f=false) .

Pour parler de friture sans que l'aliment soit complètement plongé dans un bain de friture les français parlent volontiers de [faire rissoler](http://dico-cuisine.fr/news/rissoler), ce qui correspond au *shallow-frying* anglais.

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu le terme “à grande friture” en France, peut-être dans le Larousse gastronomique ou un autre ouvrage technique ou alors dans un ouvrage d'histoire ou un livre ancien.

Comment: @Relaxed Oui, _GLG_ à beigne (_que l'on cuit à grande friture_), dauphine (_cuites à grande friture_) et villeroi (_frits à grande friture_), mais pas à _friture_ où on a plutôt les températures successives de (_moyenne, chaude, très chaude_). Le [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18061935) a p-ê. raison quand il en parle comme d'un _usage de métier_ dans les «cas où l'immersion totale dans une grande quantité d'huile est essentielle». Site de [Ricardo](https://www.ricardocuisine.com/univers-ricardo/chimie-alimentaire/454-friture-101) (Qc. pop.) avec préposition _en_ ??

Answer (score 3):

Try "cuisson en bain d'huile". I'm sure I've heard it before (or I wouldn't have thought of it so quickly). The expression is used multiple times on [this](http://www.stephan-lagorce.com/la-friture-profonde.html) cooking blog, in an entry called *La Friture*, in sentences such as:

> Il faut aussi savoir que l’ajout d’aliments nécessairement moins chauds que le **bain d’huile** dans lequel ils cuisent, fait aussitôt chuter la température de celui-ci.

*Bain d'huile* is also mentioned on other pages, such as [here](https://www.supertoinette.com/glossaire-cuisine/204/culinaire/friture.html) in the phrase

> Frire peu à la fois pour éviter le refroidissement du **bain d'huile** [...]

And [here](http://www.cuisineaz.com/diaporamas/conseils-cuisine-wok-1631/interne/recette/5.aspx):

> Heureusement, il existe une astuce toute simple pour que la viande et le poisson gardent tout leur moelleux au wok, même s'ils ne sont pas cuits dans un **bain d'huile**.

Comment: You did not allude to the reference to "cuisson en friture "profonde"" with _profonde_ in quotes in the original text of the first link you provided (Lagorce), where it is opposed to _en friture plate_. Any opinion on the usefulness of those? Thanks.

Comment: @red I asked seven of my fellow (French) students this morning and all of them thought that *friture profonde* sounded odd, and I agree (except when explicitly comparing the two ways of frying, as on the blog); only a few said that *cuire en bain d'huile* was quite descriptive. However, they all seemed to agree that *cuire à la friteuse* was the way to describe this cooking method. Personally, I find a *bain d'huile* easy to picture, and more general than *friteuse* which sounds like it's mostly for chips (which may be true in practice). But that might be my English side showing through...

Comment: Thank you, your quick poll was insightful! _Cuire à la friteuse_ also feels usual to me. Indeed, _bain d'huile_ is easy to picture... it's just I find it actually somewhat gross a picture i.e. a (bath) tub filled with oil. In such a case I would use only _(cuire) dans l'huile_  and would specificy if need be to fully immerge the food therein, to avoid using _bain_. Anyways, interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use *[pleine friture](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friture)* when you really need to specify the precise way the food is fried, although this is very rarely the case.

See for example this *beignets en piédestaux* recipe from *Les Soupers de la cour*, 1740.

[image]

Note that *pleine friture* sometimes imply the food is first immersed in batter.

Comment: @Frank Le lien vers un usage contemporain est aussi présent (wikipedia).  J'ai ajouté la recette simplement pour montrer que l'usage était ancien.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliser simplement le mot 'frit'.

Le site Linguee est très bien pour les traductions en contexte...